# Trouble with conditional style

Tags: styles, jasper-reports

thanks to everyone ,thanks to Alex K ,I'v got the cause.this is perhaps the bug of
ireport 3.0 .
the outer style tag should not contain the color property.
I delete it ,and It works well.

================================================================================
I'm come into trouble about condition style expression in report with *JasperReports*.
The verison of *iReport is 3.0*.

I just found that the boolean expression doesn't work at all.

---

The conditional style:

```
<style 
    name="old"
    mode="Opaque"
    **forecolor="#990033"**
>

    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{age}.intValue()>60?new Boolean(true):new Boolean(false)]]></conditionExpression>
        <style 
            name="old"
            isDefault="false"
            mode="Opaque"
            forecolor="#990033"
        >
        </style>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

---

The textfield expressions:

```xml
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="false" pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                <reportElement
                    style="old"
                    x="315"
                    y="0"
                    width="78"
                    height="14"
                    key="textField-3"/>
                <box></box>
                <textElement>
                    <font/>
                </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$F{age}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
```

the result is that all ages will be red even the ages less than 60;

Comment: It seems to me that your style declaration is wrong. The sample: `<style name="rowStyle" mode="Opaque">
  <conditionalStyle>
   <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{typeGroup_COUNT} % 2 ==0]]></conditionExpression>
   <style backcolor="#CCFFFF"/>
  </conditionalStyle>
 </style>`

Comment: I update the source code before. change the boolean  expression another  way and past the full code about the condition style.

Comment: It is better to post your solution as the answer

Answer (score 0):

thanks to everyone ,thanks to Alex K ,I'v got the cause.this is perhaps the bug of ireport 3.0 . the outer style tag should not contain the color property. I delete it ,and It works well.
that is :
the xml code generate by the ireport is

```
<style 
    name="old"
    mode="Opaque"
    forecolor="#990033"
>

    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{age}.intValue()>60?new Boolean(true):new Boolean(false)]]></conditionExpression>
        <style 
            name="old"
            isDefault="false"
            mode="Opaque"
            forecolor="#990033"
        >
        </style>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

this way the style is already effective .I delete the property set in the outer style tag.
so the final xml code that works well is like below:

```
<style 
    name="old"
    mode="Opaque"   
>

    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{age}.intValue()>60?new Boolean(true):new Boolean(false)]]></conditionExpression>
        <style 
            name="old"
            isDefault="false"
            mode="Opaque"
            forecolor="#990033"
        >
        </style>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```